# Lazy Pattern matching in Data.List

Tags: haskell

What are the performance benefits of using ~ (lazy pattern matching) in Data.List's partition.  Contrived examples of lazy pattern matching suggest that it is useful when the values inside the tuple constructor are never used (f (x,y) = 1).  In partition (select, below), the lists ts, fs are always used (if the predicate p applied to x is True, or not).  I'm sure this is a very well informed decision to use ~, but what is the point?  Why not strict pattern matching?

```
partition               :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
{-# INLINE partition #-}
partition p xs = foldr (select p) ([],[]) xs

select :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> ([a], [a]) -> ([a], [a])
select p x ~(ts,fs) | p x       = (x:ts,fs)
                    | otherwise = (ts, x:fs)
```

(Note: I've already looked [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lazy_pattern_match)! it doesn't answer the above question)

Comment: cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The point is that with strict pattern matching, assembling of the result could only start when the end of the list to be partitioned has been reached, in particular, `partition` would not work at all for infinite lists.

With a strict pattern match, the argument must be evaluated to WHNF. That means the entire `foldr` of the tail must have finished before it is decided whether `x` is put in the first or the second component.

```
select p x (foldr (select p) ([],[]) (y:z:ws))
~> select p x (select p y (select p z (foldr (select p) ([],[]) ws)))
```

With a lazy pattern match, a pair is constructed immediately, with `x` as the first element of the appropriate component, and the rest of the two lists to be evaluated later, when needed.